# Найти вхождение/совпадение двух массивов, либо строки в массиве

Tags: php

Вот есть шаблон города(полное название) и есть массив полученный после парсинга XML, нужно сверить на совпадение полученного массива с имеющимся шаблоном.

Например шаблон город Дубна округ Московский

Из XML город Дубна принадлежит округ Московский

Или из XML село Петушки принадлежит "Петушки" из шаблона, то есть нужно отбросить первое вхождение а это СЕЛО и сравнить имеющееся Петушки с Петушки из шаблона

Comment: Приведите реальный пример шаблона, вот прям как он у вас в коде задается и кусок XML, где есть интересующее совпадение. А так то смотрите в сторону алгоритма Левенштейна и дальше поссылкам.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно оч. хороший алгоритм, НО приходится костыли(доп условия ) от случая к случаю приписывать, Спасибо вам!:)
а помимо Левенштейна, более точный имеется способ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал примерно такой алгоритм.

Для массива XLM и шаблона

1. Все не буквенные и не численные символы заменил на пробелы
2. Все подряд идущие пробелы привел к одному символу
3. Привел строки к одному регистру(допустим верхнему)
4. Разбил строки на массивы слов
5. Отсортировал массивы по значениям

Далее три варианта

1. Либо написал функцию, реализующую алгоритм Левенштейна для двух массивов. То есть находил не коэффициент различия строк, а коэффициент различия массивов.
2. Либо склеил эти массивы обратно в строки и использовал штатный алгоритм Левенештейна(если строки сильно отличаются по длине, то чревато)
3. Проверял бы, является ли меньший массив подмножеством большего. Возможно с допуском на один элемент.

Первая часть марлезонского балета:

```
function normalize(&$value){
    $value = sort(
        mb_strtoupper(
            preg_replace(array("/[\W_]/","/ +/")," ", $template)
        )
    );
}
$template = "шаблон";
$xml = array("массив проверяемых значений");
normalize($template);
foreach($xml as &$value){
     normalize($value);
}
```

Вторую часть уж как нибудь сами.